# Tkinter - Scrollbar does not resize when number of labels inside a frame changes

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a GUI where left hand side is a `Listbox` (contained inside a frame `f2`) that displays employee ID's and right side is another frame `second_frame` (contained inside canvas and outer frame `f3`) that shows transaction details of each selected employee in the form of labels.

Each employee can have multiple transactions. So, The number of labels had to be dynamic, i.e. for first selected item in `listbox`, there could be two labels and for second selected item in `listbox`, it could be hundred. For every selection, I am calling two functions to destroy old labels and create new labels. While the code works fine, I am having trouble resizing the scrollbar according to the selected `listbox` entry. I am new to Tkinter, Please advise. Below is my code.

Also note, the test() function when called from outside any function displays the scroll bar, but does not display anything when called from within any function.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *

'''def test():
    for i in range(0,50):
        for j in range (0,7):
            Label(second_frame, text=f'{i}{j}', width=20).grid(row=i, column=j, pady=5,padx=5)
'''
# --- function ---
def destroy_frame():
    #f1.grid_forget()
    print("destroying frame")
    for label in second_frame.winfo_children():
        label.destroy()

def create_frame(val):
    print("creating new frame")
    for i in range(0,val):
        for j in range (5):
            Label(second_frame, text=f'{i} {j} ', relief=GROOVE, width=10).grid(row=i, column=j, pady=5,padx=5)

def on_selection(event):
    # here you can get selected element
    print('previous:', listbox.get('active'))
    print(' current:', listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

    # or using `event`
    print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))

    print (listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

    if (listbox.get(listbox.curselection()) == "Eid 1"):
        destroy_frame()
        create_frame(100)

    elif (listbox.get(listbox.curselection()) == "Eid 2"):
        destroy_frame()
        create_frame(200)

    print('---')


root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')

#Create base Frames
f1 = Frame(width=800, height=50, bg="yellow", colormap="new")
f1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
f1.grid_propagate(False)

f2 = Frame(width=200, height=425, bg="light blue", colormap="new")
f2.grid(row=1, column=0)
f2.grid_propagate(False)

f3 = Frame(width=600, height=425, bg="light green", colormap="new")
f3.grid(row=1, column=1)
f3.grid_propagate(False)

#Create header Label
l1_f1 = Label(f1, text="Employee Purchase Entries:", bg="yellow")
l1_f1.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Create Listbox
listbox = Listbox(f2, bg="light blue", width=40, height=400)
listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Add Scrollbar to ListBox
list_scrollbar = Scrollbar(f2)
list_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NSEW)

#Enter Listbox Data
listbox.insert(1, 'Eid 1')
listbox.insert(2, 'Eid 2')

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

#configure the Listbox and Scrollbar
listbox.config(yscrollcommand  = list_scrollbar.set)
list_scrollbar.config(command = listbox.yview)

#Create a Canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(f3, width=580, height=425, bg="light green")
#my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Add a Scrollbar to the canvas
my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(f3, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NSEW)

#configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e : my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

#Create another frame inside the canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

#Add the new frame to a window in the canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")


#test()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your canvas isnt trigger the configure event when you add widgets to your frame. Instead your frame is been triggerd.

So you need to put this line:

```
second_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e : my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

after creating `second_frame`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for!!

Comment: Is there a way to make the scrollbar start from top whenever the refresh happens? The issue that I notice is- Eid 2 has more entries and when user scrolls to the bottom of all entries, and then selects eid1, the scrollbar stops at its last position and doesnt start from top. Because of this, entries for eid 1 looks blank to users unless they scroll up. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: To scroll all the way up you would need to call `moveto` method of the canvas and sometimes its necessary to call `update_idletasks` that